# "&#63;" shows up as Restricted sign instead of "?"

Tags: html, ruby

I'm editing text on an html.erb page:

```
<body>
<div class="jumbotron center">
<h2>FAQ</h2>
    <p class="text-left">
     How do I call you &#63;
    </p>
</div>
</body>
```

The "?" should appear as a "?" but in Chrome it shows up as a Restricted sign. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why don’t you just use a question mark?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I get a restricted sign in place of the question mark then too...

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot, please? Also, are you using a webfont?

Comment: Thank you! That solves it. I'm using a Google font, Amatic, and the "?" is a known issue apparently. I just found this thread online: https://code.google.com/p/googlefontdirectory/issues/detail?id=93

Comment: Ah! Okay. Would you like to self-answer?

Answer (score 0):

As Minitech pointed out, the issue was with the web font. I just found this thread online: code.google.com/p/googlefontdirectory/issues/detail?id=93

I'm using a Google font, Amatic, and the "?" is a known issue apparently.